# Call Second Recycler view Data on click of first recycler view item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recycler-view one below another. I want to load each sub item of Second recycler-view data on item click of first Recycler-view. I am using custom RecyclerTouchListener to load data.Please let me know the proper solution.

Thanks in advance

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {

            Product allEventDatum = productList.get(position);

            categoryss = allEventDatum.getCategory();


        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This :

```
recyclerViewOne.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

        Product allEventDatum = productList.get(position);
        categoryss = allEventDatum.getCategory();

        // get your first item from first recycler view and save it in string/int
        // then pass that stored value to your API to get data according to get relevant data in the second recycler view

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
}));
```